# Multiple image upload in ruby on rails with checkbox for each image in the form and display the images in slider before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want upload multiple images at at time with each image has it is on checkbox and display each image with slider(next/previous) along with delete option, on submit form this should be save in picture table..

I have Product and Picture model with association

product.rb

has_many :images, as: :imageable, class_name: 'Picture', dependent: :destroy

picture.rb

mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader
belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true, optional: true

[image]

Instead of dropzone I need to use any other image uploader